# Measuring time interval between serial Tx and Rx in Python

Tags: python, time, usb, rs485

I've got an issue where I am trying to measure the time interval between a serial write and serial read in python. I'm using python 3.8 and a USB->RS485 adaptor on windows. Essentially, the code follows as so:

```
def write_packet(self, packet, flush=True):

      if flush:
          self.clear_buffers()

      self.ser.write(packet)
      self.tx_time = time.time_ns()
```

and this is immediately followed by:

```
def read_packet(self):      

        first_byte = True

        while True:
            byte = self.ser.read(1)
            # Check if the read timed out:
            if byte == b'':
                **(notify of timeout)**
            if byte == b'\x00':
                **(end of packet, decode and break)**
            else:    
                if first_byte:
                    self.time_rx = time.time_ns()
                    first_byte = False
```

As you can probably see, I'm trying to capture the time between just after transmitting, and receiving the first byte. After that I do something like this to get the time in ms:

```
time_diff_ms = (self.rx_time - self.tx_time)/1000000
```

My issue is the timings *time_diff_ms* seem to be way off. The scope image below of the RS485 signals shows it should read times of around ~1ms yet the script reads values of 6ms, 11ms, etc., almost random values.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJFAJ.jpg

I've also tried running the script on Linux, but not much difference. I'm also working with fairly high baud rates of 921600.

Comment: Windows is not a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system and you are using a interpreted language (Python), which also has some delay. I highly doubt that you will get values as good as the oscilloscope.

Comment: Oh absolutely, Windows is far from an RTOS. I'm essentially developing a tool here to automate the process of measuring the interval. I thought it would be possible as I've benchmarked the resolution of time_ns() on Linux even and I could achieve 48ns resolution, although maybe other python things are stopping me from getting a reasonable time. If not i'll have to look for an alternative.

Comment: There are very cheap USB oscilloscopes.

Comment: Besides the OS and the Python interpreter, your USB-to-RS485 adapter might cause some lag too.  For instance, it might have a (misguided) design where it tries to wait until it has enough data to fill up a USB packet before sending anything to the computer (with a timeout).  If you want to accurately measure something like this, a microcontroller is probably the way to go.